# Filtering of dataframe columns displaying a counter intuitive behavior (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

Take as an example the dataframe below. I need to change the dataframe by keeping only the columns that are in the *filter* objects.

```
test <- data.frame(A = c(1,6,1,2,3) , B = c(1,2,1,1,2), C = c(1,7,6,4,1), D = c(1,1,1,1,1))
filter <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
filter2 <- c("A","B","D")
```

To do that I'm using this piece of code:

```
`%ni%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
test <- test[,-which(names(test) %ni% filter2)]
```

If I use the *filter2* object I get what is expected:

```
  A B D
1 1 1 1
2 6 2 1
3 1 1 1
4 2 1 1
5 3 2 1
```

However, if I use the *filter* object, I get a dataframe with zero columns:

```
data frame with 0 columns and 5 rows
```

I expected to get an untouched dataframe, since *filter* had all test columns in it. Why does this happen, and how can I write a more reliable code not to get empty dataframes in these situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `!` instead of `-`

```
test[,!(names(test) %ni% filter2)]
test[,!(names(test) %ni% filter)]
```

by wrapping with `which` and using `-`, it works only when the `length` of output of `which` is greater than 0

```
> which(names(test) %ni% filter2)
[1] 3
> which(names(test) %ni% filter)
integer(0)
```

By doing the `-`, there is no change in the `integer(0)` case

```
> -which(names(test) %ni% filter)
integer(0)
> -which(names(test) %ni% filter2)
[1] -3
```

thus,

```
> test[integer(0)]
data frame with 0 columns and 5 rows
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simplify the column selection process by subsetting the dataframe with character vector of column names.

```
test[filter]

#  A B C D
#1 1 1 1 1
#2 6 2 7 1
#3 1 1 6 1
#4 2 1 4 1
#5 3 2 1 1

test[filter2]

#  A B D
#1 1 1 1
#2 6 2 1
#3 1 1 1
#4 2 1 1
#5 3 2 1
```